# Java 8 Stream Create an Object from Map of Objects

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I just started with learning and implementing collections via the Java 8 stream API. I have one class:

```
public class Discount {
    int amount;
    String lastMarketingRegion;

    Discount (int amount, String lastMarketingRegion) {
        this.amount = amount;
        this.lastMarketingRegion= lastMarketingRegion;
    }

    public int getAmount() { return amount; }

    public String getLastMarketingRegion() { return lastMarketingRegion; }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("{%s,\"%s\"}", amount, lastMarketingRegion);
    }
}
```

And I am given with the following:

```
Map<String, Discount> prepaid = new HashMap<String, Discount>();
prepaid.put("HAPPY50", new Discount(100, "M1"));
prepaid.put("LUCKY10", new Discount(10, "M2"));
prepaid.put("FIRSTPAY", new Discount(20, "M3"));

Map<String, Discount> otherBills = new HashMap<String, Discount>();
otherBills.put("HAPPY50", new Discount(60, "M4"));
otherBills.put("LUCKY10", new Discount(7, "M5"));
otherBills.put("GOOD", new Discount(20, "M6"));

List<Map<String, Discount>> discList = new ArrayList<Map<String, Discount>>();
discList.add(prepaid);
discList.add(otherBills);
```

So, basically I have a list of `Discount` maps of all discount codes for different payment types.

Requirement is to create a single map with all the discount codes across all payment types with `sum_of_amount` and the `last_region`:

```
Map<String, Discount> totalDiscounts = 
{LUCKY10={17, "M5"}, FIRSTPAY={20, "M3"}, HAPPY50={160, "M4"}, GOOD={20, "M6"}}
```

I am able to get:

```
Map<String, Integer> totalDiscounts = 
    {LUCKY10=17, FIRSTPAY=20, HAPPY50=160, GOOD=20}
```

by using the following code:

```
 Map<String, Integer> afterFormatting = discList.stream()
                           .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
                           .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.summingInt(map -> map.getValue().amount)));
```

but I need a `Discount` object also with the region.

I need a collection of Discount objects where the amount is the total of the amounts of same key and region is from otherBills.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank You.

Edit 1 - 
For the sake of simplicity, please consider lastMarketingRegion to have same value for a discount code.
I also tried to explain it via diagram - [image]

Comment: Why do you expect "LUCKY10" - "M5" when you have "M2" and "M5" entries for LUCKY10?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please be more precise on your requirement. Explain it cleanly so that we can help you.

Comment: @daniu because otherBills has more priority than prepaid.

Comment: @ernest_k yes, I need a collection of Discount objects where the amount is the total of the amounts of same key and region is from otherBills.

Comment: @ankitrai please add the explanation you've given here into the question

Comment: @RavindraRanwala Please let me know what is not clear. I will try to elaborate more.

Comment: @ankitrai Show me the final output needed? It's data type?

Comment: I went ahead and added toString, getters and missing angel bracket so it would roughly match your desired output. Feel free to remove if you don't agree.

Comment: added also your comment to the question to make it less ambiguous.

Comment: @eis Thanks a lot for the chnages done. Much appreciated.

Comment: `discList.forEach(entry -> {
            entry.keySet().forEach(key -> afterFormatting .merge(key, entry.get(key), Discount::merge));
        });` and merge method is `public Discount merge(Discount discount){
        this.amount+= discount.amount;
        return this;
    }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From comments

> Why do you expect "LUCKY10" - "M5" when you have "M2" and "M5" entries for LUCKY10?
>
> because otherBills has more priority than prepaid

You can use `Collectors.toMap` for this. The last argument to it is the `mergeFunction` that merges two Discounts that had same String key in the map.

```
Map<String, Discount> totalDiscounts = discList.stream()
            .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue,
                    (discount1, discount2) -> new Discount(discount1.getAmount() + discount2.getAmount(),
                            discount2.getLastMarketingRegion())));
```

Since the stream generated out of a list is ordered, the `discount2` *Discount* will be the one from the `otherBills` map and hence I'm picking the region of it.

If you have constructed the list by adding `otherBills` followed by `prepaid`, then this will have a different output.

Relying on the encounter order makes this a *not-a-great-solution*.
(If you are going to assume we process entries from the second map after processing the first, why merge them in the first place?)

See my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52126612/4405757) that uses `Map.merge`

Comment: @nullpointer I have edited the answer stating the assumptions

Comment: @nullpointer My solution only picks `M5` and not `M2` since (2<5). I couldn't understand your point

Comment: Your solution worked. Thanks a lot for the help.. Time for me to probably get my hands dirtier in stram api.

Answer (score 2):

If you have just two maps, then rather than going for a stream-based solution (my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52126399/4405757)), you can use `Map.merge` for this.

Here, we make a copy of the `prepaid` map. Then we iterate through the `otherBills` map. For each key

1. If the mapping does not exist, it adds it to the map (result map)
2. If the mapping already exists, we construct a new `Discount` object whose amount is the sum of amounts of the Discount object already present in the map (the one from `prepaid`) and the current Discount object (the one from `otherBill`). It takes the region of the Discount object from the `otherBill` map.

---

```
Map<String, Discount> result = new HashMap<>(prepaid);
otherBills.forEach((k, v) -> result.merge(k, v, (discountFromPrepaid, discountFromOtherBill) ->
        new Discount(discountFromPrepaid.getAmount() + discountFromOtherBill.getAmount(),
                discountFromOtherBill.getLastMarketingRegion())));
```

Comment: IMHO, preferably better than creating a `List<Map<K,V>>`